# How to open python xlsx file as a spreadsheet?

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I have a data.xlsx file. When i open it, a notepad window comes up with some data which is not human readable. 
But when I right click on the file and select 'open with' microsoft excel then a window opens up in which I can see all the cells arranged (in grid format).
I want to open data.xlsx file in this format using python. How can i do this? 

I tried using 
`import os`
`os.system("data.xlsx")`
but this opens the file in the notepad format and not in the spreadsheet excel format.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to use Python to run Microsoft Excel and be able to specify which file to open in that application? Your question is rather confusing especially given that you've tagged *openpyxl*

Comment: Have a look at openpyxl or pandas to work with excel files. But without more info on what you want to do with the file, it is impossible to help any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use python to run a terminal command to launch excel with the file as a parameter:

```
import os
os.system("start excel C:\path\to\file.xls")
```

Comment: Answer assumes OS is windows

Comment: Your answer works. Thanks. I had another question. Is there any way in which I can also do the above thing but somehow also mention which sheet of the workbook gets opened?